# OpenCL Kernel language: possible bug when using the if statement without curly braces

Tags: opencl

Here are the opencl kernel codes. This does not work:

```
__kernel void testKernel(__global const int* srcA, 
                        __global const int* srcB, 
                        __global int* res, 
                        const int num)
{
        const int idx = get_global_id(0);

        if (idx < num)
            res[idx] = srcA[idx] * srcB[idx];
}
```

And the log for the above code is ":12:2: error: expected identifier or '('
 }
  ^"

However, if you include braces, then it works. Here's the working code:

```
__kernel void testKernel(__global const int* srcA, 
                        __global const int* srcB, 
                        __global int* res, 
                        const int num)
{
        const int idx = get_global_id(0);

        if (idx < num)
        {
            res[idx] = srcA[idx] * srcB[idx];
        }
}
```

I understand that opencl kernel language follows C99, but if I understand C99 correctly, braces are needed only if you have multiple lines of code under the if statement. Does anyone know why I am getting these errors?

Update:
after rewriting the if statement, the error is not showing up anymore. i can't reproduce the error.

update: the error is showing up again, but it goes away again if I use the spacebar instead of tab to indent the one line of code underneath the if statement

update: after rewriting it, the kernel can be compiled now. it's not the tab.

Comment: opencl kernel is based on C, but it is a subset of C all aspects of C aren't guaranteed to work; I would expect that to work though...

Comment: Are you sure the code you're looking at is actually being fed into OpenCL properly? I once had a bug similar to yours that was caused by not passing the correct parameters to clCreateProgramWithSource.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading the kernel from a file, make sure to add a '\0' character at the end of the array you store it in, otherwise the compiler will become confused and appear to act in a non deterministic fashion.

Adding brackets and spaces often makes the kernel work, but it isn't the root of the problem.

I know this is an old post, but please test it as there are multiple unanswered forum posts around the interwebz on this issue.